# Is there exist a notion of determinant for linear operator between space the same dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let linear operator $T: E \to F$ with $\dim E = \dim F = n$. Is there exist a notion of determinant of $T$,  and/or  eigenvalue of $T$?

Note that doesn´t make sense that: $Tv=\lambda v$ because $v \notin F$.

Thanks

Comment: Although there is an isomorphism $J:F \to E$. The value $\det(JT)$ depends on $J$. In fact, I am even not sure if $\det(JT) = \det(TJ)$. So, I am not sure if such notation makes sense in case of $E\ne F$.

Comment: It might be interesting, if $E,F$ have at least a metric. But, then the orientation matters, so we need at least an inner product and orthonormal bases with the same orientation.

Comment: In every finite dimensional space the norms are equivalente, so you can put a inner product in $E$ and $F$. Buy how can you define the determinant and eigenvalue?

Comment: no, you will need an isometry which preserves orientation. But that is just wild guessing.

Comment: There certainly is for an endomorphism.  But as user251257 notes, for $T:E\to F$, you'd probably need to map $F\to E$ via an isomorphism and then the determinant will depend on *which* isomorphism you choose.

Comment: So, the determinat will depend of the basis chosen. Is it?

Comment: @Alladin: Yes, which it shouldn't ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider two vector spaces  of dimension $1$. Can we identify a unique number to an isomorphism between them? (For example consider two lines in the plane).  This requires a choice of non-zero vectors in both the spaces.

Given a linear map $T\colon V\to W$ for vector spaces of the same dimension, one can talk of the associated map on the exterior powers $T_r\colon \wedge ^r V\to \wedge ^r W$. For $r=\dim V$ this becomes a linear map of 1-dimensional bases. Any choice of bases in $V$ and $V$ would lead to canonical choice of bases in these 1-dimensional bases and so lead to a scalar associated to the map of 1-dimensional spaces. This ois the determinant map associated to $T$.

Comment: I'm not sure. Note that $T_{r}: \wedge^{r}W \to \wedge^{r}V$ take $T_{r}(f) \in \wedge^{r}W$. By definition, $T_{r} (f) (v_{1},...,v_{r})= f (T(v_{1}),...,T(v_{r}))$, where $f \in  \wedge^{r}W$ and $T: V \to W$. If it's correct,   $T_{r}(f) = \lambda f \in \wedge^{r}V$, that is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can relabel the elements of $F$ so that the target space is just the initial space $E$.  Because dim(E) = dim(F), there is an isomorphic mapping - a one-to-one correspondence - between the elements of E and the elements of F.

Without relabeling, then I don't see how this makes sense, in the context of basic linear algebra.

Also, the spectral theorem, the theory of eigenvalues and eigenvectors always (to my knowledge) start with letting some linear operator map some space $v$ -> $v$.  So it is by definition that you are mapping from one space to itself.  Although I understand your question - and have myself asked this question to my linear algebra professor in the past.  (His response was that it doesn't always have to be from $v$ -> $v$, but he never elaborated on any special cases, so I cannot say much more.)

Comment: what you call relabeling is a isomorphic mapping...

Comment: right @user251257, I will edit to add this information in.  Thanks,

Comment: If you use a isomorphic mapping, so the determinant and eigenvalue will depend of this isomorphic mapping

Comment: Jeremy Lin, thanks for sharring

Comment: sure thing @Alladin - good luck.